# I can't connect to MySQL server in any way (on Windows)

Tags: mysql

My problem is below:

```
C:\Users\ordek> mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using 
password: NO)

C:\Users\ordek>mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
password: NO)

C:\Users\ordek>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ****
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
password: YES)
```

I tried lots of solutions before asking here. I've even tried reinstalling MySQL but surprisingly this problem still exists. In Workbench I can't connect to any connection. I always login to the MySQL server as superuser and subsequent attempts to change privileges didn't work because I can't log into MySQL in the usual ways.

In Workbench it doesn't matter which user: root or not, you'll get this message.

```
[Window Title]
MySQL Workbench
[Main Instruction]
Cannot Connect to Database Server

[Content]
Your connection attempt failed for user 'user1' to the MySQL server at 
127.0.0.1:3306:
Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Please:
1 Check that MySQL is running on address 127.0.0.1
2 Check that MySQL is reachable on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, 
but this can be changed)
3 Check the user user1 has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your 
address (MySQL rights define what clients can connect to the server and 
from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the 
correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're 
connecting from
```

In "test connection"(WORKBENCH) I always get this message:

```
[Window Title]
MySQL Workbench

[Main Instruction]
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user user1

[Content]
Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

In my mind this is a problem with privileges, but I don't know what to do because I'm a beginner at MySQL. If you know how to overcome this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Please follow the steps on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html and [edit] your question to include the result and output you get when you execute each step. Also write the exact steps you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you installed MySQL (windows) using .msi package.  As it .msi allows you to do the installation step by step and you can set "root" password.

If you have root password, make sure MySQL services are started.

Control panel > services > Mysql

Comment: yes, i set password after install, but it still can`t go throught. I`ve checked, really MySQL service isn`t installed... only MyDB, idk what is this

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-service.html  see whether this helps..

Comment: It`s done, ty. Sorry for dumb question, that was really trivial situation... Anyway thanks for tip.

Answer (score 0):

The user **ordek** seems unknown to mysql . Switch to root user and it will work .
If this is not possible ,  or the root password is unknown , re-install mysql , make a note of the root password for future use , create the **ordek** user and assign it the access rights it needs .

Comment: i made it system variable. But if you insist, this didn`t work too